# how can we feed multiple stock data and get multiple output?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, stock, forex

[image]Usually, we do predictions on data for example USD/GBP which consists of columns HIGH, LOW, OPEN, CLOSE. This is only a prediction on a single dataset. And my question is how can I do prediction on multiple data such as USD/GBP, EUR/USD, XAU/USD, USD/JPY. Feeding all this data to a single model and getting predictions on all this dataset i.e multiple outputs. Is this possible?? Thank you.

Comment: if the other datasets are have the same features and columns and the training of the model has been done in contact of these datasets as well then you can append all the dataframes into a single DataFrame on which you want to have the predictions. But yes this a generic approach and depends on your dataset and code which you have written. Its always a good to provide sample dataset and code for which question is being asked

Comment: I mean to say that how can I train the model with 8 columns HIGH, LOW, OPEN, CLOSE, HIGH1, LOW1, OPEN1, CLOSE1 and get 2 predictions one on the first 4 columns and the second on the last four columns.

Comment: The generic approach will be to slice the DataFrame in two parts with first 4 columns ```df1 = df.iloc[:,0:3]``` and last 4 columns ```df2 = df.iloc[:,4:7]``` and then making predictions on these two dfs seperately using your ```model.predict()``` but to again re-iterate depending on how you have trained your model

Comment: Cant, we do training and prediction at once rather than doing it separately on the df1 and then the df2?

Comment: Your question is not clear , are you still in model building stage? or have already build a model? Incase you are building a model then you have to create two dataframes and have to have ```test, train``` separately or can do a single training by appending last 4 columns to first four column ```(high, low,open,close)``` provided you have done the preprocessing correctly on each currency value. And if you already have pre-build you can utilise to predict ```df``` as you want

Comment: Have a look at the image which I added

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question correctly what you want is to feed in data to a model which has two models in it and run on one model `(model1 or model2)` seperately according to the data fed into it. For this you can create a model class with the minimal interface which will create a `model` which will select based on the value of the feature

As an illustration:

```
import pickle as pkl
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

#Combined of both df1 and df2
data= {
 'HIGH': [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'LOW': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
 'OPEN': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 'END' : [3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0]
 'target_price': [0.0, 2.0, 1.5, 0.0, 5.1, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.1, 1.5]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data) 
X, y=df.iloc[:, :-1], df.iloc[:, -1]
X= X.astype('float32')

# create two models                 
model1= LinearRegression()
model2 = LinearRegression() 
ser_model1= X['x']==0.0
model1.fit(X[ser_model1], y[ser_model1])
model2.fit(X[~ser_model1], y[~ser_model1])

# define a class that mocks the model interface
class CombinedModel:
    def __init__(self, model1, model2):
        self.model1= model1
        self.model2= model2
        
    def predict(self, X, **kwargs):
        ser_model1= X['x']==0.0
        return pd.concat([
                pd.Series(self.model1.predict(X[ser_model1]), index=X.index[ser_model1]),
                pd.Series(self.model2.predict(X[~ser_model1]), index=X.index[~ser_model1])
            ]
        ).sort_index()

# create a model with the two trained sum models
# and pickle it
model= CombinedModel(model1, model2)
model.predict(X)
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as fp:
    pkl.dump(model, fp)
model= model1= model2= None

# test load it
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
    model= pkl.load(fp)
model.predict(X)
```

**OR** if you want to *ensemble*

then use [VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)

The idea behind the voting classifier implementation is to combine conceptually different machine learning classifiers and use a majority vote or the average predicted probabilities (soft vote) to predict the class labels

Comment: can't we do this with just one model?

Comment: I think you should be clear in your requirement. There are two different things if you have two models for two datasets and want to run the model as per need to dataset then above answer would work and if there you want to ```ensemble``` the models and get the results then you can use ```VotingClassier```. I have updated my answer for both cases, choose whatever fits in your case